# Java Generics Selective Return Value

Tags: java, parsing, generics, methods, return-value

I've been struggling with this for a while and have yet to find an answer.  As a result, my brain is somewhat muddled, so pardon me if I make a dumb mistake.

I'm trying to implement a typed INI parser, that will parse this kind of file:

```
[section1]
<int>intkey=0
<float>floatkey=0.0
<str>stringkey=test

[section2]
<float>x=1.0
<float>y=1.0
<float>z=0.0
```

In doing so, I have a central class named `Config`, which handles the basic reading and writing operations.  One of the methods of `Config` is called `get(String section, String key)`, which ideally would return a value appropriate for the requested section-key pair, like so:

```
Config cfg = new Config("test.ini");
cfg.get("section2", "x"); // 1.0, not "1.0" or some Object that technically represents the float
cfg.get("section1", "intkey"); // 0
cfg.get("section1", "strkey"); // "test"
```

I'm currently using an `enum` to handle the conversion of the `String` to various types, with an `abstract` method overridden by the different types:

```
enum Type
{
  INTEGER ("int") {
    public Object parse(String value) {
      try
      {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e)
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
  },
  FLOAT ("float") {
    public Object parse(String value) {
      try
      {
        return Float.parseFloat(value);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e)
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
  },
  STRING ("str") {
    public Object parse(String value) {
      return value;
    }
  };

  public final String name;

  Type(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  private static HashMap<String, Type> configMap = generateConfigMap();

  private static HashMap<String, Type> generateConfigMap()
  {
    HashMap<String, Type> map = new HashMap<String, Type>();
    for (Type type : Type.values())
      map.put(type.name, type);
    return map;
  }

  public static Type get(String name)
  {
    return configMap.get(name);
  }

  abstract public Object parse(String value);
}
```

Unfortunately, `parse(String value)` returns an Object, and when passed out of `Config`, requires a cast or similar, and ideally this would be self-contained.

If I'm going about this completely wrong and there's a more flexible or simple way to code it, please let me know.  I'm open to suggestions.  Though I would like to know if there's a way to do this.  Maybe with generics...?

Note: I know I'm missing imports and the like.  That's not why I'm posting here.

Comment: There is a way to do it, but you had better know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing.  If the code that calls `config.get()` doesn't know what type to expect, you can't possibly return anything other than Object since the calling code doesn't know what to expect.  Of course you'll have to cast.

Now, if you wanted to design `Config` in a way that the caller *did* know what type it was asking for, than that becomes a bit easier.  The easiest approach then is to do something like this:

```
public class Config {
    public int getInt(String a, String b) {
        return ((Integer)get(a, b)).intValue();
    } 
}
```

But until the caller knows what to expect, you really gain nothing from avoiding casts.

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem is, that removes the dynamicity that the `enum` provides.

Comment: @CMC: You're trying to be static and dynamic at the same time.  Sorry to break the news, but you have to choose one or the other.  Either the caller knows what type to expect and your framework supports that, or it doesn't know and has to inspect it first.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  So there's no way to accomplish this?

Comment: @CMC: You haven't really expanded on what "this" *is* that you're trying to accomplish.   I'm trying to say that your requirements are invalid, not impossible.  They don't make any sense.  Perhaps if you could give a concrete example of what you're trying to do?  Generics would only help if you're trying to *assign* `config.get()` to some variable, but in your example you're not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a a type of object depending on what you get you can do this:

```
public <T extends MyObject> T myMethod(Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(myObj);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be based on the type specified in the .ini file.  in calling the `get(String section, String key)` method I don't want to have to specify what type to return.

Comment: ... How do you know what the type is in the INI file? What happens if the type in the INI file isn't what your code (or your calling code) expects?

Comment: I was planning on having an internal default config file to use as a reference, but now that you mention it, I really don't have that much control...